# Is the river that Jaime falls into real?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This question has been bothering me ever since I watched the ending of the fourth episode of season 7 (*The Spoils of War*).

Jaime charges towards Daenerys and Drogon. He is charging along the bank of a river; so, it seems that the water is obviously not that deep (maybe ~0.1 Jaime Lannister). Now, someone hurls him from his horse and they fall into the water, and suddenly, the river seems deeper than seven Jaime Lannisters (see below screenshot).

The point at which he falls isn't that far from where the horse was riding along the bank. So my question is - do real rivers behave like this? That kind of gradient seems scary if it can be real. And if so, does anyone know of any particular rivers that might do this?

[image]

Comment: Funny, [I had the same question](https://twitter.com/IamMooz/status/895054504479014913)

Comment: Also, your question title doesn't quite match up with the body. Are you asking whether the final sequence is Jaime hallucinating or whether similarly deep-near-the-bank rivers exist in our real world?

Comment: @Mooz - My question is - can such a river (naturally) exist and if so, does it exist? I think the title and body are aligned around this, but feel free to suggest modifications.

Comment: I like that you measure the river's depth in Jaimes :D

Comment: The Patuxent river drops about 80 feet in 2 meters which is quite a scary drop. They exist but are likely quite rare. Blackwater rush has been described as a VERY deep river. Although I don't think the speed of the drop has been described.

Comment: Anecdotally, I can confirm the same for beaches. In Belgium, the beach has an incredibly soft slope. From getting my feet wet, to the water coming up to my neck (as a 12 year old), can be about 50m (up to 100m in some places). But the beaches in the south of France came up to my (12 year old) neck **within 3m**.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Though not explicitly described, it is called the Blackwater **Rush**. I would infer that it's a fast flowing river; which would mean that it erodes relatively quickly and could easily create a deep ditch profile (assuming a straight part of the river).

Comment: Which is exactly why it's been described as being very deep. Although it is fantasy land so I don't want to assume the rate of erosion at the banks.

Comment: I am now more interested in Bronn and Jaime's breath holding capacity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a sample river cross-section from the coolgeography.co.uk [articles on meanders and floodplains](http://www.coolgeography.co.uk/GCSE/AQA/Water%20on%20the%20Land/Meanders/Landforms%20Meanders.htm).

[image]

So **yes**, not only can this type of river exist, children are even taught about it in school.

Comment: Lucky for Jaime he was on the right side of it!

Comment: Firstly, this only occurs at bends in the river, and 2 is a very simplified version of a river cross-section. This actually is a mockery of what a river cross-section actually looks like. Oh yeah merge your accounts!

Comment: You can look [here](https://www.google.ch/search?q=river+cross-sections&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9m6iq3cnVAhUDsBQKHYjmC58Q_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=676) for not only more children's drawings as have been provided, but also actual plots of data from **real** rivers showing what real river banks look like.

Comment: +1 For using an image from a text book I used whilst at school

Comment: Well this river cliff does not look like the one in the serie. There is no cliff in the scene, the horses are already in the water and it is not deep.

Answer (score 6):

> Is the river that Jaime falls into real?

Yes and we can clearly see it in a few of the shots from before Jaime falls into the water.

[image: Jaime and Bronn look over the supply train]
<sub>Jaime and Bronn look over the supply train</sub>

[image: Drogon burns the supplies next to the river]
<sub>Drogon burns the supplies next to the river</sub>

As for where your confusion comes from well it actually appears to be a mistake on the show's part as Jaime is clearly seen before falling in riding through very shallow water.

[image: Jaime charges Drogon and Dany]
<sub>Jaime charges Drogon and Dany</sub>

When they manage to dodge Drogon's fire they then fall into what still appears to be shallow water.

[image: Jaime and Bronn fall into the river]
<sub>Jaime and Bronn fall into the river</sub>

Then when we see Jaime start sinking it is all of a sudden extremely deep and Bronn is nowhere to be seen. Though of course he might be at the surface still seeing as he could swim.

[image: Jaime drowning]
<sub>Jaime drowning</sub>

---

On an anecdotal note my grandma's house backs onto a river and we used to jump off the garden into it all the time and it was *very* deep and this was on a straight and at the edge.